# How do I create a one-click publishable installation for a DLL?

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I have a Class library that has dependencies like Entity Framework, etc.

I wish to deploy this to another machine, but the publish option is not visible for class library projects.

How do I create a one-click publishable installation for this DLL?

Comment: I suggest that you explore [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx) technology in order to deploy your library.

Comment: I have, and all it talks about is deploying a high level package such as an application or website. Nowhere have I found documentation for clickonce where all I am deploying is a set of class libraries. Even the option to publish disappears from the dropdown menu when you right click on the project.

Comment: Then, you should check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx) out. It may help you.

Comment: For what reason would you want to deploy a class library to another machine? Is it to be used in another application or another dev environment?

Comment: The C# Class Library enables images to be uploaded to Azure. The current website is Classic ASP using VB6, so I need to migrate the C# DLL with dependencies onto the testing server and then hopefully onto production.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The C# class library alone allows NOTHING - except when it is used. So why do you want an installer for a class library? Make one for your application.